# Implements stack using linked list - is all this code needed?

Tags: linked-list, stack

I code what implementing stack using linked list as I coded I look some of code that somebody coded I have something awkward.

The point that I ask is what is different when I use

```
if (top == NULL){
        top=temp;
        top->next=NULL;
    }
```

this part with when I don't use this. Is it needed? In my opinion that part is needless.

This is my full code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define Max 5

struct Node{
    int value;
    struct Node *next;
};

struct Node *top;
int count;

int main(){
    int pop();
    void push(int);

    int stack_full();
    int stack_empty();

    void printStack();

    void init();
    void freeAllRes();

    int opt;

    int value;

    init();
    printf("initialization is performed!\n\n");

    printf("1. Push to stack");
    printf("\n2. Pop from Stack");
    printf("\n3. values in Stack");
    printf("\n4. Exit\n");


    while(1){
        printf("\nChoose Option : ");
        scanf("%d",&opt);
        switch(opt){
            case 1:
                if(stack_full()==-1){
                    printf("Error : Stack is full!!");
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    printf("\nEnter a value to push into Stack : ");
                    scanf("%d",&value);
                    push(value);
                    break;
                }

            case 2:
                if(stack_empty()==-1){
                    printf("Error : Stack is empty!!");
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    printf("Popped num : %d ",pop());
                    break;
                }

            case 3:
                if(stack_empty()==-1){
                    printf("Error : Stack is empty!!");
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    printStack();
                    break;
                }

            case 4:
                freeAllRes();
                printf("All resources are free!");
                exit(0);

            default:
                printf("Error : wrong choice!!");
                break;
        }
    }
}

int stack_full(){
    if(count==Max)
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int stack_empty(){
    if(top==NULL)
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}

void init(){
    top=NULL;
    count=0;
}

void freeAllRes(){
    struct Node *temp;
    while(top!=NULL){
        temp = top->next;
        free(top);
        top=temp;
    }
}

int pop(){
    int popNum;
    struct Node *temp=top;

    popNum = temp->value;
    top = top->next;
    free(temp);
    count--;
    return popNum;
}

void push(int num){
    struct Node *temp;
    temp=(struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    if(temp==NULL){
        printf("Error : malloc fail!!");
        exit(0);
    }

    temp->value=num;
    /*
    if (top == NULL){
        top=temp;
        top->next=NULL;
    }
     */
    //else{
        temp->next=top;
        top=temp;
    //}
    count++;
}

void printStack(){
    struct Node *temp=top;

    printf("\nElements are as:\n");
    while(temp!=NULL){
        printf(" %d ",temp->value);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}
```

And how to I code this code fancy and efficient and nice?

Comment: Seems code you have commented is unnecessary.Top is null when you add the first item , so "temp->next=top" is same as "top->next=NULL"

Comment: then,  why many people code like that with unnecessary code? if you search in google you can find many people code including that part